# Increase a variable by 1 in loop for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, var

I have been writing javascript/jquery for about 2 days so I know very little.  I have a set of variables that I am pulling from a page.  I then write back to a database using API a duplication of that information x number of times.  I am using a loop to complete the x number of times.  I have a variable called newBar.  It starts out being defined by adding 1 to another variable called curBar.  What I am having trouble with is I need newBar to increase by 1 each time the loop is completed.  I can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this.

```
$(document).on('Start.view-render.view_536', function (event, view, data) {
var curBar = Start.models['view_536'].toJSON().field_173;
var barCount = prompt("How many total barcodes to generate?");
var loopCount = --barCount;
console.log( loopCount );
var newBar = ++curBar;
// Add a button to execute the action
$('#' + view.key).prepend('<button id="copy-button">Duplicate Barcodes</button>');

    var duplicateInventory = {
        field_170: data.field_170_raw[0].id, //Customer
        field_171: data.field_171_raw[0].id,//inbound order
        field_173: newBar,//barcode
        field_178: data.field_178_raw[0].id,//Product
        field_185: data.field_185,//product type
        //field_443: data.field_443_raw[0].id > 0 ? data.field_443_raw[0].id : "",//batches-order item
        field_175: data.field_175,//date received
        field_186: data.field_186,//semi-finished weight
        field_176: data.field_176,//Inbound Container #
        field_177: data.field_177_raw[0].id,//warehouse
        field_183: data.field_183,//inbound verified
        field_221: data.field_221_raw[0].id,//order item
        //field_352: data.field_352_raw[0].id > 0 ? data.field_352_raw[0].id : "", //STO
        };
    // Add the duplicate function to the button we just added
    document.getElementById('copy-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++){ //start duplicate loop
            $.ajax( {
                url: 'https://api.somedomain.com/v1/objects/object_10/records/',
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {'X-Application-Id': 'xxxx', 'X-API-Key':'xxxx'},
                data: duplicateInventory,
                success: function(response) {      
                 // alert('Record Copied!');
            }
        });
        }//End of Loop
    });
});
```

Comment: After the `for( ... ) { ... }` add `loopCount ++;` to increase the variable.

Comment: Put `newBar++` in the loop?